# ECMAScript 6 spread syntax in object deconstruction. Support in TypeScript and Babel

Tags: javascript, typescript, ecmascript-6, babeljs, typescript1.5

Is the following valid ECMAScript 6?
It seems to be supported by the latest version of Babel but it isn't by TypeScript.
I couldn't find any ES6 references dealing with this case.

```
var a = { foo : 'foo' };
var b = { ...a };
```

Comment: Some of the `...` uses in objects are ES7 proposals, not ES6.

Comment: @Pointy Is right. Switch off Experimental mode and you'll get an error `Unexpected token`

Comment: Also you can check the compatibility table @ http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/

Comment: [Apparently `...` is not an operator.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35028879#comment57784206_35029020)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

No, this is not valid ECMAScript 6. ES6 does only support rest syntax in function parameters and array destructuring, and spread syntax in function calls and array construction.

> It seems to be supported by the latest version of Babel

Babel does implement the [objectRestSpread ES7 proposal](https://github.com/sebmarkbage/ecmascript-rest-spread) as a [experimental plugin](http://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/#experimental). You shouldn't use this feature, it may break at any time.

Comment: The 2nd link is broken

Answer (score 0):

TypeScript 2.1 does support this feature.

[Here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-1.html#object-spread-and-rest)

Answer (score 0):

I was making following mistake

```
const o = { p : { q:1, r:2 } };
const {{q,r}} = o;
```

> later realized that it is important for me to **direct** `q` and `r` **from p**, so it was basically a syntax error in my case, so corrected code with following syntax.

```
const {p:{q,r,s=9}} = o;
console.log(q,r,s); // 1,2,9
```