# Object Destructuring and Rest parameters

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, babeljs

I'm using the following syntax and getting an error `Unexpected token` when babel transpiles my script. But when I run the same script in their 'try it out' online compiler, it runs fine. What is wrong with my Object Destructuring and or Rest parameters?

```js
function onDestructure({one,two,three,...ten}) {
    console.log(ten)
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Rest syntax in object destructuring](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31115276/1048572) is not in ES6. You've probably enabled the "experimental" features in the online compiler.

Comment: Can you suggest a way to get the unnamed parameters?

Comment: @colecmc: What do you mean by "unnamend parameters"? How are you calling that function?

Comment: The object I receive has a bunch of keys, but I only need the first few `{one,two,three}` for the moment. If I need the others, is there an alternative to naming each one? `{one,two,three,four,five,six,seven,eight,nine,ten,eleven}` I guess I can use standard syntax at that point by just saying `data` and grabbing what I need: `data.one, data.two`

Comment: Just use `function(options={}) { const {one, two, three} = options; …}`, then you can access all of them dynamically as properties of `options`.