# Add props to ...this.props

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm passing down a list of props to children components like {...this.props} however have encountered a case where I need to add additional props, I believe I can do it like `<Child {...this.props} addProp="myNewProp" />`, however to keep code cleaner, can I somehow add `addProp` to the list of `...this.props`, so I only pass it down?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<Child {...{addProp:"myNewProp", ...this.props}}/>
```

(but, in my opinion, usual JSX attribute syntax looks better it your example)

Also, you should remember that although this syntax [supported](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/syntax-object-rest-spread/) by Babel's plugin, it is [still a proposal](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31116409/916330) and could not be included in actual ES7.

Answer (score 0):

You can use JavaScript:

```
h(Child, {
    ...this.props,
    addProp: "myNewProp"
})
```

`h` is just alias: `const h = React.createElement` or [JSnoX](https://github.com/af/JSnoX)